# Want to select an element by xpath, but it same xpath value in multiple tab

Tags: python, testing, xpath, automation, playwright

I want to select an element by xpath, but it has the same value in multiple tabs, the only one which different is the class set name when that tab is selected like "morning_select" and it is kind of a sibling to the element I need.
I try to take the sibling and then navigate to my need tag:

```
xpath="//li[@class='morning_select']//..//..//following::div/ul//a[@title='same content in every tab']"
```

But even with the difference, Playwright will click on the same tag of multi-tab.  Have anyone met the same issue? It has same structure and same CSS style for all tabs

Comment: You should post the HTML of your page in a code block, so we can understand what the XPath needs to do. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format code.

Comment: Every tab has its one `page` instance. I bet you are using the wrong one.

Comment: @hardkoded, I'm working on it, so basically there are 4 tabs on the same page and we not define each page for each tab, I just need to click on <a> tag on one tab, even though the xpath I found cannot find when you change tab, on Playwright it just see it as the same on 4 tabs and click all of it.

Comment: you should add more details such as the URL or the HTML content of the page you're targeting to bring you the help.